# Jade looping through keys/values returning same value multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Got the Node.js part down. First time around with jade and don't totally grasp its looping structure.

On the node side: I am iterating through the s3.listObjects key/values in my bucket and parsing out the prefix value content.This checks out on the server side.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

var params = {
    Bucket: 'mybucket',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'myprefix/'
}

s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {

    var count = data.CommonPrefixes
    for (var key in count) {
        if (!count.hasOwnProperty(key));
    }
    var obj = count[key];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop));
    }
    var results = obj[prop];
    console.log(results);// Returns 83 Prefix values


    res.render('entry', {
        title: 'ENTER PROJECT INFORMATION', lists: results
    });
  });
});
```

Jade Side:

```
 block content
 div#wrapper
    h1= title
    div#status
    ul
    each list in lists          
            li= lists
```

This is returning the 83rd prefix 83 times in the li tag. I know the looping is off but the jade iteration docs are pretty scarce.What's the give? Thanks All!

Comment: `li= lists` vs `li= list`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `li= lists` which will show the entire array, assuming you want to be looping through, you need to do

```
// For explanation
var lists = [1, 2, 3];
//

li= lists // [1,2,3]

li= list // [1];
```